# Nemo in Linux Mint - Reset all Preferences and "My computer" pane in List View

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, gtk, nemo, gtk2

I am struggling a little bit  with this issue I'm having with Nemo in Linux Mint (I just upgraded to 17.3 but this is happening since 17.1).

In brief, I accidentally removed some shortcuts from the "My computer" section in the left sidebar of nemo as a user. I tried to restore them, nbut apparently I can't add icons to that tab, nor drag them from the "bookmark" section to the "My Computer" one. If I start nemo as root, I can add, remove, drag and drop icons in that tab, but of course the changings does not apply to the "user" version.

Moreover, I tried to perform a clean install of nemo after purging it, but unsuccessfully.

Can someone explain me where th configuration file of this sidebar are located and hot to delete them, or set their permission to user in order to drag and drop correctly into that tab? Alternatively, is there a "real" way to clean install Nemo and only Nemo without touching the other GTK features?

Thanks a lot for your time, any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I use dconf-editor for a lot of settings which are otherwise not reachable.
The settings of nemo are in the branch org.nemo.preferences.
I have not managed to alter the settings for the elevated nemo ("as root") so far. When dconf-editor is started per sudo or gksu it simply doesn't respond.

Answer (score 0):

Install dconf-editor, and navigate there to org->nemo->preferences. Maybe there you will find your settings? They are named pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that I never noticed this behavior before. You can only drop a shortcut on specific places in Nemo. Say for instance, you cannot drop a shortcut between Home and Desktop. You can however drop a shortcut below Desktop. That's the way it works for me anyway (using Mint 18). In my case, I am dragging a folder from the center 'viewer' to the left pane, under 'My computer'.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem with the `dconf` editor.

1. Add/remove/sort bookmark list in Nemo using Bookmarks/Edit (Lesezeichen/Bearbeiten). Add missing entries you like to have in "My Computer" section of sidebar.
2. Start dconf Editor. Browse to section `org/nemo/sidebar-panels/window-state`.
3. Doubleclick value of parameter "sidebar-bookmark-breakpoint" (standard value is -1).
4. Play with the value by clicking on [+] and [-] and watch the bookmark list.

This value defines the position in the list of your bookmarks where the "Computer" ("Mein Rechner") and the "Bookmarks" ("Lesezeichen") section are separated.

A little bit tricky, but I managed to customize the sidebar exactly as I wanted to.